# Grep reports non-existent file

Tags: shell, grep

This is somewhat abstract and curiosity of mine. I ran across this today and I don't understand how it could happen.
I have a directory tree that would look like, both project directories are fairly large:

```
Work/
  project1/
    ...
  project2/
    ...
```

From within `Work/project2/` I would run a command like `grep -rin 'some string' ../project1/`. Among other output I would see a line like `grep: ../project1/../..: No such file or directory`.
I don't understand how this would happen. As I thought the shell (zsh in this case I suppose) would be interacting with the filesystem and only returning existing files. How does this location end up reaching grep's input?

Answer (score 1):

The given file is likely symlink. The target of which is no longer existing. A "broken link". In this case grep is operating on the true location, to which the link points.